# adding html textbox value in php variable

Tags: php, variables, sum

I want to sum values in a php variable from html text box my php code is as under

```
$total = 0;
$val2 = $_POST['val1'];
$total += val2;
echo "Sum of value is ". $total;
```

This is my HTML:

```
<form action="add.php" method="post" >
  <input type="text" name="val1" />
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: this is my html code

Comment: '<form action="add.php" method="post" >'
'<input type="text" name="val1" />'

Comment: Sum should then be $total

Comment: when i give first value in text box it shows the first value ,but as i give the value second time it doesnot sum the previous value with new one and display only last value given

Comment: Because PHP is a server side programming language and it runs at first. next time u will need to refresh the page

Comment: @irfan see my edited answer on sessions...done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sessions;

```
session_start();
$val2 = $_POST['val1'];
$total = 0;
if(isset($_SESSION['prev_sum'])){
    $total = $_SESSION['prev_sum'] + $val2;
}else{
    $total += $val2;
}
$_SESSION['prev_sum'] = $total;

echo "Sum of value is ". $total;
```

Comment: i tried this code but it is not sum the second value given in text box .

Comment: it set the $total value to 0 when i enter value in text box next time

Answer (score 2):

use `Session`

```
session_start();
$total = 0;
$val2 = $_POST['val1'];
$_SESSION["total"]+= $val2;
echo "Sum of value is ". $_SESSION["total"];
```

> A session is a way to store information (in variables) to be used
>   across multiple pages

Comment: What will happen if the $_SESSION["total "] is not set ..? especially when it runs for the first time? @Rahautos

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't working ,it is showing  "sum of value is val2 " every time i enter a value in text box

Comment: session_start();
$total = 0;
$val2 = $_POST['val1'];
$_SESSION["total"]+= $val2;
echo "Sum of value is ". $_SESSION["total"];

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like

```
session_start();
$val1 = isset($_SESSION['val2']) ? $_SESSION['val2'] : 0 ;
$val2 = $_POST['val2'];
$total = $val1 + $val2;
$_SESSION['val2'] = $total;
echo "Sum of value is ". $total;
```

AND

```
<form action="add.php" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="val1" value="<?php echo $_POST['val1'] ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="val2" />
....
```

Comment: it showing the value i entered in text box .but when i enter next value in text box it does't sum the second value in $total variable

Comment: no sir i want to use one text box ,every time i enter a value in text box it should be sum in $total variable and shows the result new value

Comment: In that case, You can use the solution provided by `William Madede. use session to store old value. I have editied the answer. please have a look

Answer (score 0):

`$total+=$val2` refers to `$total = $total + $val2` so the `values` are being summed up in the variable `$total` instead of `$val2`. So replace `$val2` in `echo` statement with `$total`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use sessions or database(which is not suitable for your current problem) for this because http is stateless protocol i-e it cannot maintain its state so as soon as new request originates all the variables set to its default values

```
session_start();
$sum= 0;
$val2 = $_POST['val1'];
$_SESSION["sum"]+= val2;
echo "Sum of value is ". $_SESSION["sum"];
```